# How to have LINE app Friends sorted in Hanyu Pinyin order?

Tags: line, locale, chinese-language

In [Sort contacts by Hanyu Pinyin](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/251008/sort-contacts-by-hanyu-pinyin/251010) one manages to sort contacts in Hanyu Pinyin order. Alas, with LINE app Friends it seems there is no way to get other than simple Unicode ([radical](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_(Chinese_characters))) sorting.